# regex any number or type followed by ".pdf"

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to write a gsub function that will remove any records that end with `.pdf`. My attempt `gsub(".*([A-Z][1-9][.pdf]?).*", "", "12asdf.pdf")`.

Comment: Do you want to match the whole string if it ends with .pdf? [`.*\.pdf$`](https://regex101.com/r/CB9BeQ/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression that you need is:

```
gsub(".*\\.pdf$", "", "12asdf.pdf")
```

This replaces any string ending in `.pdf` with the empty string

Answer (score 1):

The `stringr` package (part of the `tidyverse` ecosystem) has a function `str_remove` which searches for a regex pattern and replaces the first match with a blank (or `str_remove_all` which removes all matches in the string). It's a shorthand for setting `""` as a replacement in `gsub` or other functions.

As for the regex, `^.*\\.pdf$` will match the beginning of a string starting with any zero or more characters (i.e. it's optional to have characters before ".pdf") through ".pdf" at the end of the string.

```r
files <- c("doc1.pdf", "doc2.pdf", "picture1.jpg", "doc3.pdf",
           "bad.pdftitle.xlsx", ".pdf")
stringr::str_remove(files, "^.*\\.pdf$")
#> [1] ""                  ""                  "picture1.jpg"     
#> [4] ""                  "bad.pdftitle.xlsx" ""
```

Comment: fails on `".pdf"`

Comment: @snoram that would be a pretty weird file name but fair enough, I'll edit accordingly